# I have a question about examdoclass document class

Tags: exam

I have a problem with \qformat command. What should I write in "Format specification" to have something like this:
[image]

and not like this:

[image]

First version I do manually, the second one is done by \question command. I'd like to have "Question" and content in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must redefine the question label and point units.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
    
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\textbf{Question \thequestion.}} % added <<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand{\points}{p} % added <<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question[3]What did Billy Joe MacAllister throw off the Tallahatchie Bridge?       
    \end{questions}
    
\end{document}
```